# How to avoid overwriting files while writing multiple files from BLOB data in DB in JAVA

Tags: java, blob, outputstream

I am retrieving data from DB BLOB(csv) data into CSV files . While writing the data  into files each and every time the files are getting over write . Below the code I used for writing the files . If I close the writer inside the for loop then , only one file gets writes others are not getting loaded. If I closed outside the loop  then same file gets overwrites every time .

//code:

```
while (rs.next()) {
                String filename = rs.getString("file_name");
                String path = ( calPath + filename );
                File file = new File(path);
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file ,true);
                Blob blob = rs.getBlob("file_data");
                byte[] bytes1 = blob.getBytes(1l, (int) blob.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes1.length; i++) {
                     output.write(bytes1);
                                                                   //output.close();
                }

                output.close();

            }

            //connection.close();
```

Comment: have you checked your file name in db. Is file name is similar for every file?

Comment: what is the purpose of inner for loop in your code. Inner for loop is overwriting you file

Comment: @kandy Inner loop is to write multiple files from DB there will be number of files need to be convert from Blob to CSV

Comment: I am writing the blob data from DB to CSV file after fecthing the file i am writing it in the Inner loop but the iteration is non stops after writing a file for first while checking for the next file it writes to the first file also

Comment: remove your for loop and check

Comment: @kandy Yeah that worked due to loop it writes the file multiple time . after removing the Loop working fine . thanks for the assistance

Comment: I have added an answer for you post. If this work then please accept answer and up vote so that it can help other in future.

Answer (score 0):

Due to your inner for Loop it writing file again and again. so remove your inner for loop it will work.

```
 while (rs.next()) {
            String filename = rs.getString("file_name");
            String path = ( calPath + filename );
            File file = new File(path);
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file ,true);
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("file_data");
            byte[] bytes1 = blob.getBytes(1l, (int) blob.length());
           // for (int i = 0; i < bytes1.length; i++) {
                 output.write(bytes1);
                                                               //output.close();
           // }

            output.close();

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you should check file first.
you can write if file not exist

```
    File file = new File(path);

    if(!file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) { 
        // do your writing?
    }
```

EDIT: also you can compare sizes if you want more specific comparison

Comment: will it write for the first file which  never existed in the path before

Comment: it will write file if file is not existing

Comment: The above is not writing the file as expected